# Feature Request: Colab OAUTH to github for cloning/pulls etc

Tags: google-colaboratory

We can already oauth Colab .ipynb files from github into the colab enviroment.

Would it be possible to support oauth as a general Colab <> github authentication, so we don't need to use this third party SSH keygen solution (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tsunrise/colab-github/main/colab_github.py)

Comment: The new Secrets feature is awesome, that fixes this request really (I mean oauth to Github directly would have been cleaner, but this allows you to store an SSH key).

Comment: Nope, it doesn't you still need the colab_github code - because you need to transfer the secret into the .SSH file in order for SSH to work. So close. And even then, its not ideal, as you'd be copying the SSH key between every single colab you worked on. What it kind of needs is a "global colab secrets" (and SSH support).